# Real world workflow samples needed

Tags: 2007, workflow

I need some real world workflow scenarios and sample implementations. Simple two step approval workflow don't help me.

Can someone provide some references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some that I think go a little deeper than most in terms of SPD workflows:

http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.com/2008/10/task-escalation-using-workflows.html

http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.com/2009/02/give-blood-to-your-workflow.html

Laura Rogers has a few simple ones here (with links to others):

http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Categories/Category.aspx?Name=workflows